# What does the following union signify?

Tags: c, unions

```
struct  ifreq {
    char    ifr_name[IFNAMSIZ];             
    union {
            caddr_t ifr_d;
    } ifr;
};
```

Here they have used union, I didn't get the point why have they used when there is only one element used there?
I have a idea of using union only if there are 2-3 elements that need to be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loads of possibilities. But, in this case, it looks like it's because the definition was cut out of the corresponding Linux header, and they just took the parts they needed. `struct ifreq` looks like this, normally:

```
struct ifreq {
    char ifr_name[IFNAMSIZ]; /* Interface name */
    union {
        ...
    };
};
```